# SapUI5 includeScript is not loading js files in fiori launch pad

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-controls, sapui5, openlayers-3

I have a UI5 component on instantiating that component I start loading OL3 library like this,

```
var promise = jQuery.sap.includeScript({
                     url : //ol3Path,
                     id : 'ol3'
                 })
promise.then(function(){
   console.log("OL3 library loaded.");
})
```

And I am trying to instantiate this component inside the UI5 custom control and placing that inside the div that I created in the custom control renderer And i am instantiating this custom control in **FIORI Launchpad**,  So in summary on instantiating that custom control, I load libraries.
but after loading like this I am getting that console message also but once I loaded this there is a global variable **ol** I am not able to access this variable.How to fix this?

[image: Loading ol library][image]
[image]

Comment: Do you see the file loaded in network trace? Is there any failing request (probably 404) at that time?

Comment: all files are loaded.

Comment: Any script errors? You have a link to the included script?

Comment: @ cschuff No errors it's adding respective script tags in HTML page also and loading the files also but not able to access any of the variables or functions from the loaded files.Actually, I have a custom control on instantiating that control I will start loading js files.

Comment: I guess it is either an issue with your external script or a timing issue. Can you show a little more code?

Comment: I have created the same scenario in a test program but there it will work fine.But when we are instantiating inside the fiori launch pad then it's not working.

Comment: Did you try this way: jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("ol3",ol3Path);
jQuery.sap.require("ol3.ol3"); Once registered (place registerModulePath in Component.init) you should be able to load ol3 with AMD as well.

Comment: I have tried it its not working.

Comment: I am trying to instantiate this custom control in the FIORI launchpad is it a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the problem, Currently, i am using **requirejs** in my fiori project so if there is **requirejs** then all other ways of loading the library will not work. So once I removed **requirejs** then it's loading all the libraries properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the below blog: https://blogs.sap.com/2013/02/11/sapui5-with-google-maps/

(or)

When you want to use external API's in component file use your code and use jQuery.sap.registerModulePath(). Tis will make your global variable work.

Comment: I don't have to registerModulePath once that ol file is loaded then we can access variable ol.But it's not happening